# WebAPI - Admin pages to CRUD business objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Before I endeavor to create this myself, I want to ask: is there any packages out there for ASP.NET WebAPI that allow one ApiController to do CRUD on all my business objects?

Right now, I have the annoying situation that I have to create "BookController", "AppleController", "LightController" etc... for every single Admin page that lets a user CRUD Books, Apples, and Lights.

The "BookController", "LightController" etc... are so similar that it is painful for me to have to keep creating these things.

I have a lot of business objects, and they keep coming, and each of them needs a CRUD.  So doing this:

Example:

```
class BookController: ApiController 
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id=-1) { // do the read operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Book b) { // do the create operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(Book b) { // do the update operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(Book b) { // do the delete operation }
}
```

Isn't scalable for my situation.  I'd rather replace BookController and all other CRUD controllers with something like this:

```
class CRUDController: ApiController 
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id=-1) { // do the read operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(object obj) { // do the create operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(object obj) { // do the update operation }
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(object obj) { // do the delete operation }
}
```

Any suggestions or hints?

Comment: Is there any non CRUD behaviour? I.e. will you need to be able to add other actions for any of the business objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a generic base controller.

```
class CRUDController<T> : ApiController
{
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Get(int id=-1) { // do the read operation }
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Post(T obj) { // do the create operation }
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Put(T obj) { // do the update operation }
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Delete(T obj) { // do the delete operation }
}
```

Then inherit your controllers from it.

```
class BookController : CRUDController<Book>
{
    ...
}
```

One thing to note is that you will need repositories to be injected if you use that pattern in your controllers. If not, the code inside the base controller would become spaghetti.

Comment: this is definitely a good suggestion...  I'm looking for a way that doesn't require me to add any new controllers for each type of business object.  But depending on how difficult that proves to be, I might end up just going with this solution.  Because I know that I'd have to do something special with my routes if there isn't a BookController. (for example)